# Error de version en Google Maps en Flutter

Tags: flutter

Hoy quise compilar mi App y me encuentro con que la version de GoogleMaps caduco, al menos entiendo eso. Dejo el error que me sale:

```
Compiler message:
lib/lista_negocio_detalle/map.dart:44:15: Error: Method not found: 'MarkerOptions'.
              MarkerOptions(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/lista_negocio_detalle/map.dart:54:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'trackCameraPosition'.
        trackCameraPosition: true,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
file:///C:/Users/Emi/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/git/plugins-9017d6e7f867af278edd7e8e584d52524f37443f/packages/google_maps_flutter/lib/src/google_map.dart:18:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const GoogleMap({
        ^
Compiler failed on C:\Users\Emi\AndroidStudioProjects\vivi_carhue\lib\inicio_splash\main.dart
         *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of google_maps_flutter will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See https ****** for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

este es mi codigo de la clase map:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class map extends StatefulWidget {
  String x, y;
  map(this.x, this.y);
  Marker _selectedMarker;
  @override
  _map createState() => _map(x, y);
}

class _map extends State<map> {
  String x, y;
  _map(this.x, this.y);
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    GoogleMapController myController;

    final Maps = Container(

      height: 100.0,    //altura
      width: 40.0,   //anchura
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 30.0,
        left: 30.0,
        right: 30.0,
        bottom: 60.0,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
          boxShadow: [new BoxShadow(          //SOMBRA
            color: Color(0xffA4A4A4),
            offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
            blurRadius: 3.0,
          ),]
      ),
      child: GoogleMap(
        onMapCreated: (controller) {
          setState(() {
            myController = controller;
          });
          myController.addMarker(
              MarkerOptions(
                  draggable: false,
                  position: LatLng(double.parse(x), double.parse(y))
              )
          );
        },
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        scrollGesturesEnabled: false,
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        compassEnabled: false,
        trackCameraPosition: true,
        /*MarkerOptions: MarkerOptions(
            position: LatLng(double.parse(source)x, double.parse(source)y) ;
          ),*/

        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          tilt: (25.0),
          zoom: 15.9,
          target: LatLng(double.parse(x), double.parse(y)),
        ),
      ),
    );

    final texto = Container(
      child: Text(
        "Ubicación",
        style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16.0,
        color: Colors.black
        ),
      ),
      width: 50.0,
      height: 10.0,
      );

    return Maps;



  }




}
```

y este es mi pubspec.yaml

```
name: vivi_carhue
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  wave: ^0.0.8
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.2.0
  url_launcher: '>=0.1.2'
  http: ^0.12.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  google_maps_flutter:
      git:
        url: git://github.com/flutter/plugins
        path: packages/google_maps_flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  fonts:
  - family: Monika
    fonts:
    - asset: fonts/Monika.TTF
  assets:
      - fotos/fondo.jpg
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

error al compilar:

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\Emi\AndroidStudioProjects\vivi_carhue\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Multiple projects in this build have project directory 'C:\Users\Emi\AndroidStudioProjects\vivi_carhue\android': [:vivi_carhue, :]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Command: C:\Users\Emi\AndroidStudioProjects\vivi_carhue\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El package de `GoogleMaps` está actualizándose constantemente, el equipo de Flutter aún no recomienda usarlo en producción, y tener mucho cuidado ya que en cada momento están rompiendo cosas.

El error que mencionas es porque en la versión más reciente ya no se usa `MarkerOptions` ni `trackCameraPosition`.

Si usas el callBack the `onCameraMove`, asume que `trackCameraPosition` es true.

```
 GoogleMap(

   onCameraMove(position){

   }
 ...
 )
```

También cambió la forma de agregar Markers, lo puedes ver en este ejemplo : https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_marker.dart

Ya no hacen uso de `MarkerOptions`

Comment: Sabes cual es la ultima version? No la encuentro. La que tengo es la 0.4.0

Comment: La última publicada la puedes ver aquí: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter#-versions-tab-   , pero ojo, tu estás apuntando directamente a la url del repositorio, por lo cual puede tener cambios que aún no han sido publicados:  https://github.com/flutter/plugins/commit/808a596755c16e8f37f9c65e85160b583ff1e24c

Comment: Uh que quilombo, ahora no me deja compilar... Edito publicacion con el error

Comment: Puedes usar una versión anterior si te causa muchos problemas:  google_maps_flutter: 0.3.0+3